# tmux ctrl-p now scroll not working

Tags: tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using ubuntu in WSL2 and Windows terminal preview, with `tmux` in daily usage. The `ctrl-p` key in copy-mode works normally for months, but today after a sudden windows hangs, I restart the Windows machine, the `ctrl-p` key and in `ctrl-n` copy-mode doesn't move the cursor anymore. I have checked that:

- No manually configuration file changed
- Left and Right key in tmux copy mode works normally
- `ctrl-p` and `ctrl-n` can be used to show history commands in terminal
- `ctrl-p` and `ctrl-n` works normally in vim
- `ctrl-p` and `ctrl-n` works normally in man page
- `ctrl-space` also doesn't work for tmux copy mode(can't begin to select text)

The current `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```bsh
#### COLOUR (Solarized 256)

# default statusbar colors
set-option -g status-style fg=colour136,bg=colour235 #yellow and base02

# default window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-style fg=colour244,bg=default #base0 and default
#set-window-option -g window-status-style dim

# active window title colors
set-window-option -g window-status-current-style fg=colour166,bg=default #orange and default
#set-window-option -g window-status-current-style bright

# pane border
set-option -g pane-border-style fg=colour235 #base02
set-option -g pane-active-border-style fg=colour240 #base01

# message text
set-option -g message-style fg=colour166,bg=colour235 #orange and base02

# pane number display
set-option -g display-panes-active-colour colour33 #blue
set-option -g display-panes-colour colour166 #orange

# clock
set-window-option -g clock-mode-colour colour64 #green

# bell
set-window-option -g window-status-bell-style fg=colour235,bg=colour160 #base02, red
bind '"' split-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind % split-window -h -c "#{pane_current_path}"
bind c new-window -c "#{pane_current_path}"
```

The current key bindings for my tmux shows from `C-B ?` is:

[image]

I have also reinstalled `tmux`, but the problem hasn't been fixed. What can be the root cause? Any work-around or suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: Your Ubuntu packages may have updated following your Windows hang.  I'm running the newest version 3.2 and don't see Ctrl n or p in the Copy Mode section of `man tmux` for either Emacs or Vi mode.  These bindings may well have changed.

Comment: @AndrewM. This may be the reason, I have reinstalled the whole system after hours of trying. I will check version 3.2 soon or later. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewM. It happens again, this time it happens just after I compacted the hard disk, because the WSL consumes too much disk and never returns to Windows. I have checked that the tmux version is `tmux 3.0a`, seems to haven't been upgraded automatically.

Comment: That's crazy: Linux especially without a GUI shouldn't use much space.  Maybe it's time to dual boot or do what I do: run Linux over SSH from a VPS like Digital Ocean or Linode.  I think there's a VS Code extension to make that look local.  Anyway: check `man tmux` to see what the bindings are for your version.  That's how to be sure.

Comment: @AndrewM. There is a notorious [issue](https://stephenreescarter.net/how-to-shrink-a-wsl2-virtual-disk/) for WSL' s disk usage. I will not consider using ssh since our server is so far from our office and it's painful to use ssh. I have checked the man page, seems we are close to the root cause. The man page shows that there are no `ctrl-p` and `ctrl-n` in copy mode now, and I followed the key binding map, then find I can finally start copy with `space` and end copy with `enter`.

Comment: In my previous comment, I find that the `vi` mode works, so I think it may be caused by my configuration for `export EDITOR=vim`, then I unset the `EDITOR` and manually upgraded `tmux` to 3.1d, then the problem is gone. Thank you so much for the kindly help!